# ANDROID CROP: Crop with square shape

Tags: android, image, save, crop

I'm trying to crop in a square shape the pictures from Gallery and from the Camera. From the gallery works perfect, the gallery opens, I choose the picture and then the crop frame keeps always the shape of a square even when I resize it. But when I do the same for a picture that I take from the camera, the crop frame keeps the rectangular shape no matter what I change in the code.

I read that this can be changed with the `aspectX` and `aspectY` but I still get the same results.
Currently my code is the following:

```
Intent i = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
            File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),  "photo.png");
            i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
            i.putExtra("crop", "true");
            i.putExtra("outputX", 320);
            i.putExtra("outputY", 320);
            i.putExtra("aspectX", 320);
            i.putExtra("aspectY", 320);
            i.putExtra("scale", true);      

            mUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
            startActivityForResult(i, CAMERA_PICTURE);
```

Does any body have a way to configure the crop frame to always keep the square shape?...
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You really want to do this way?

Try make bitmap and some drawable attach canvas to bitmap a draw to canvas that drawable
and save bitmap.

If you have problem with it maybe a can write you 
// but create bitmap from file
//

```
BitmapDrawable returnedBitmap = BitmapDrawable(String filepath); // here you create image with size of image
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(returnedBitmap); // here you attach canvas to bitmap
drawable.draw(canvas); // here you tell to you drawable that you want to draw to this canvas drawable know canvas size and it automatically resize it self to fill canvas. Also you can read another image an use it.
```

and maybe you call resize function to make certain size.

**The Drawable** :) this is what i mean mean just make outer color a make inner transparent

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <gradient android:startColor="#554C5466" android:centerColor="#55334255" android:endColor="#ff3D5A99" android:angle="270"/>
    <stroke android:width="1px" android:color="#ffffffff" />
    <corners android:radius="10dp"/>    
</shape>
```

and save bitmap to file

Comment: Thanks @Mertuarez, but can you please elaborate a little more with a small example? I don't understand in what part of this code the image will be cropped with the shape of the square and also in the size of the square I need. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Try out this way :

> ```
>     Bitmap m_bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(m_Path);
>      Intent m_cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
>     // indicate image type and Uri
>     m_cropIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(m_Path)), "image/*");
>     // set crop properties
>     m_cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
>     // indicate aspect of desired crop
>     m_cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
>     m_cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
>     // indicate output X and Y
>     m_cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 256);
>     m_cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 256);
>     // retrieve data on return
>     m_cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
>     // start the activity - we handle returning in onActivityResult
>     startActivityForResult(m_cropIntent, 1);
> ```

Comment: Thanks @Grishu but I'm running away from `com.android.camera.action.CROP` since is not recommended.